# How do I anchor part of a django page?

Tags: django

There is a link to contacts (they are on the main page at the bottom) and I need to click to transfer the user to the specified part of the page

```
<li class="menu__item menu__item_footer">
                    <a href="{% url 'main:index' %}" class="menu__link">Контакты</a>
                </li>
```

views.py:

```
class ContactView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    form_class = EmailForm
    success_url = 'main/index.html'
    success_message = "Письмо успешно отправлено"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        send_mail('Caparol_Center_Spb',
                  'Теперь вы будете получать лучшие предложения шоу-рума',
                  settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                  [email, ],
                  fail_silently=False,)
        success_message = self.get_success_message(form.cleaned_data)
        if success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, success_message)

        if not Subscriber.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            Subscriber.objects.create(email=email)
        return redirect(reverse('main:index'))
```

Comment: You add the anchor at the end, so something like `<a href="{% url 'main:index' %}#anchor-name" class="menu__link">Контакты</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first giving `id` attribute, you can give this to any tag you want (e.g `<p id="paragraph"></p>`). In your case it is where you want to go.

Then add id's reference in your anchor tag e.g. `<a href="{% url 'main:index' %}#paragraph" class="menu__link">Контакты</a>`.